# Как посчитать угол наклона прямой в градусах?

Tags: javascript, тригонометрия

Имеется два `<div>`, у них `position: absolute`

1. x1 = 50px, y1 = 150px;
2. x2 = 100px, y2 = 200px;

Расстояние между ними  - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу задать угол наклона(с помощью `transform: rotate`), а потом нарисовать линию между точками.
Коэффициент угла наклона прямой равен тангенсу угла(противолежащий катет делить на прилежащий катет в прямоугольном треугольнике)
Формула, по которой можно посчитать коэффициент угла наклона прямой: `(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`
Как задавать этот угол в градусах?

Comment: проще наверное прочитать учебник по геометрии :))

Comment: @Leks я сдал ЕГЭ на 90 баллов, но никогда не высчитывал угол наклона прямой :D, решал какие-то сложные параметры, а такие вещи не решал, и зачем оно всё

Comment: угол = арктангенс((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) * 180/3.1415

Comment: @Эникейщик точно! А я забыл, спасибо. Там легкая формула, на ЕГЭ было это, забыл(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ладно, угол... вот с позиционированием после поворота надо повозиться)

Треугольник из точек-линий (на случай, если прилетят инопланетяне и отключат нам SVG):

```js
let pointSize = 5;

setPoints();
drawLines();

function setPoints(){
  let points = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');
  points.forEach( elem => {
    let [x, y] = elem.dataset.coors.split(",");
    // (?) Google → Деструктурирующее присваивание.
    
    elem.style.left = x + 'px';
    elem.style.top = y + 'px';
    elem.style.width = elem.style.height = pointSize + 'px';
  });
}

function drawLines(){
  let lines = document.querySelectorAll('.line');
  let PI = Math.PI;
  
  lines.forEach( elem => {
    let [x1, y1, x2, y2] = elem.dataset.points.split(/,|\s/).map(Number);
    
    // .map(Number) → map получает встроенную функцию Number(), и из полученных строк
    // от dataset, сразу делает число, чтобы не было сюрпризов "1" + "1" = "11" 
    
    let lineLength = ( (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 ) ** 0.5;
    let angle = Math.atan( (y2-y1) / (x2-x1) ) * 180 / PI; // Искомый угол в градусах
    
    elem.style.width = lineLength + 'px';
    elem.style.transform = `rotate(${ angle }deg)`; // (?) → Интерполяция строк
    elem.style.top = ( y1 + (y2-y1)/2 + 2 ) + 'px';
    
    let cos = Math.cos( angle * PI / 180 );
    let x0 = Math.min(x1, x2);
    elem.style.left = ( x0 + lineLength * (cos - 1)/2 + pointSize/2 ) + 'px'; // (*)
  });
}
```

```css
.svg {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #123;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg">
  <div class="circle" data-coors="200,50"></div>
  <div class="circle" data-coors="250,100"></div>
  <div class="circle" data-coors="50,200"></div>
  
  <div class="line" data-points="200,50 250,100"></div>
  <div class="line" data-points="250,100 50,200"></div>
  <div class="line" data-points="50,200 200,50"></div>
</div>
```

**(*)** `x0 + lineLength * (cos - 1)/2 + pointSize/2` — x0 и pointSize понятно - необходимый сдвиг слева, чтобы остальное уже вычислять "с нуля". А откуда получилось `lineLength * (cos - 1)/2` еще не придумал, как объяснить) Было понятно, что что-то связанное с sin или cos - час крутил и вертел разные палки, методом тыка нашел)

Comment: Очень интересно!